# How to generate automatic Rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Below Sample Table

```
month   year    budget_Amt   Actual_Amt

feb     2017      25         30

mar     2016      10         5 

apr     2016      50         15
```

I am executing following query

```
select month,year,budget_amt,Actual_Amt from Table where month in('Feb','Mar','apr')
```

I need following output

```
month   year    budget_Amt   Actual_Amt

feb     2017      25         30

mar     2016      10         5 

apr     2016      50         15

QuarterYTD 2016   85         50
```

4th record will generate automatically when I execute query

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data given, you could `UNION` in grouping like the following.  However, I assume that your data is more complex and some additional code would need to be added to the query.

```
select month,year,budget_amt,Actual_Amt from Table where month  in('Feb','Mar','apr') 
UNION ALL 
select 'QuarterYTD', Year, sum(budget_amt), sum(Actual_Amt) from Table where month in ('Feb','Mar','apr')  group by Year
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer  .But condition on  month is based on what user require it may be only feb or feb and mar